# Lightbox gallery with ACF and Slick

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, slick.js

I'm trying to create a gallery with lightbox images.
I use the ACF gallery field to add the images and Slick Lightbox to have a lightbox.

I always get the same error but I can't fix it: Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).SlickLightbox is not a function
All other files seem te be loaded, but only this error stays.

Demo link: https://vdp-staging.dfib.be/cases/case-voorbeeld/

**Page template:**

```
<div class="case__content">
    <img src="<?php the_field('case_uitgelichte_afbeelding') ?>">
    <?php the_field('case_tekst'); ?>

    <?php $beelden = get_field('case_beelden');
    if($beelden): ?> 
        <div class="case_gallery"> 
            <?php foreach( $beelden as $beeld ): ?> 
                   <a href="<?php echo $beeld['url']; ?>" target="_blank" class="thumbnail"> 
                       <img src="<?php echo $beeld['sizes']['thumbnail']; ?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" /> 
                   </a> 
            <?php endforeach; ?> 
        </div> 
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

**How I enqueue my scripts into my plugin-file:**

```
function wp_enqueue_all_scripts(){
    wp_enqueue_style( 'slick_css', '//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.5.0/slick.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style('slickcsstheme', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'slick/slick-theme.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style('slickcsslightbox', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'slick/slick-lightbox.css' );

    wp_enqueue_script( 'slick_js', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'slick/slick.min.js', array('jquery'), '', true );  
    wp_enqueue_script( 'slick-lightbox', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'slick/slick-lightbox.js', array('jquery'), '', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'vdp-cases', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'scripts.js', array('jquery'), '1.0', true );
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wp_enqueue_all_scripts');
add_action( 'init', 'cases', 0 );
```

**scripts.js**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){ 
    jQuery('.case_gallery').SlickLightbox({ 
        itemSelector: '> a' 
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This has been answered here -> [Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).slickLightbox is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59041159/uncaught-typeerror-jquery-slicklightbox-is-not-a-function)

Most likely slick.min.js contains lightbox js as well. Try removing lightbox js and see what happens.